# QR factorization: How to get decreasing r_ii

Tags: matrices, factorization

Hi,
I'm attempting to implement a QR factorization with column pivoting so that the returned R matrix has decreasing diagonal elements (that is, $r_{i,i} \leq r_{i-1,i-1}$ for all $i\geq 2$). Mathematically, it would involve finding the matrix $P$ so that $AP=QR$, or $A=QRP^T$.
I'm using Gram-Schmidt to compute QR.

One source I found was this: http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/250632

Quote from the answer:
"During the iteration #k, it is easy to show that if we pick among the set of remaining vectors (i.e., not yet included in the span) the vector that has the *largest* orthogonal component to the current subspace (generated by k first vectors), then the diagonal of R must decrease."

Sounds simple enough, but HOW do I determine which vector of the remaining ones that have the largest orthogonal component to the subspace that's already been found?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help on this matter!

Best regards
Hallgeir

Comment: Is there any reason why you prefer Gram-Schmidt (you're using the modified version I hope, classical Gram-schmidt has piss-poor numerical stability) over using Householder reflections?

Comment: Seconded. Also, check if you can link to the relevant LAPACK subroutine (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node42.html) instead of coding it from scratch.

Comment: Hi, these are reasonable points of course, but the whole point was to learn how to actually implement it. And I do indeed use the modified version. :) I learn better by doing, and as such I find that implementing the algorithm is a useful way of achieving that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each step $k$, choose the column of the "reduced" working matrix $A(k:n,k:n)$ with largest Euclidean norm and bring it in front with a permutation. Notice that $r_{11}$ is the Euclidean norm of the first column...

Comment: A little late reply from me (seems the email notification came quite late), but thank you very much! :) Seems to work perfectly!